# Typesafe activator 1.3.9 no longer works (regarless of the version)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

Just downloaded and installed `activator` 1.3.9 for Play-Scala 2.3.8 on a new fresh Ubuntu 15.10 box (jdk 8, scala 2.11.6 were already installed).

The problem is that the `activator` no longer works and I always get the following errors (even with the latest version of the `activator`):

```
j3d@gonzo:~$ activator 
Getting com.typesafe.activator activator-launcher 1.3.9 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.9

    ==== local: tried

      /home/j3d/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.9!activator-launcher.jar:

      /home/j3d/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/jars/activator-launcher.jar

    ==== activator-launcher-local: tried

      file:/opt/activator-1.3.9-minimal/repository/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.9!activator-launcher.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.jar

    ==== typesafe-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.9!activator-launcher.jar:

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/ivys/ivy.xml

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.9: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/activator-launcher-1.3.9.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.9/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.9: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/j3d/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve activator-launcher 1.3.9
```

Tried to remove `.sbt`, `.ivy2`... but no way. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it. The problem was the JDK. My Ubuntu box had OpenJDK-8 installed on it... but the activator doesn't work with it (don't ask me why). Eventually I just removed OpenJDK-8 and installed Oracle's Java 8. Now it works.

Comment: hope u filed a bug with openjdk team so they can fix the problem